# Accounting Overdue Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to get open invoices and overdue (if any).

I have a table named "Invoices" with this basic structure:

```
InvoiceNo   CustID  InvoiceDate Amount  DueDate     Credit
1           1       01/04/2015  120.00  01/31/2015  
2           2       01/13/2015  72.00   01/20/2015  
3           1       01/12/2015  63.00               TRUE
4           2       02/18/2015  43.00   02/10/2015  
5           2       02/24/2015  16.00               TRUE
```

A table named "Payments" reflecting the customers payments:

```
PaymentNo   CustID  PaymentDate Amount  Refund
```

I have also an "Opening Balance" value for each customer

I need to be able to see on the query results of customers having a balance <> 0.  Something like that:

```
CustID    Balance   Amount Overdue   Days Overdue
```

I use this query to show open invoices, it works fine but I'm stuck with the overdue deal.

```
Select Customers.CustID
     , Customers.DisplayName As 'Name'
     , COALESCE(Customers.OpeningBalance,0) 
     +(( Select COALESCE(Sum(Invoices.Amount),0) From Invoices Where Credit = 0 And Invoices.CustID = Customers.CustID )  
     +( Select COALESCE(Sum(Payments.Amount),0) From Payments Where Refund = 1 And Payments.CustID = Customers.CustID ) ) 
     -(( Select COALESCE(Sum(Invoices.Amount),0) From Invoices Where Credit = 1 And Invoices.CustID = Customers.CustID ) 
     +( Select COALESCE(Sum(Payments.Amount),0) From Payments Where Refund = 0 And Payments.CustID = Customers.CustID )) as Balance
From Customers
Where Exists ( Select * From Invoices 
               Where Invoices.CustID = Customers.CustID )
```

@Zajonc
The overdue balance is calculated according to the invoice amount and the payment amount relatively to their dates.

Scenario:
assuming a customer has an invoice #1 with a due date dated 01/15/2015 and with the amount of 140.00 
assuming that that customer made a payment of 40.00 on the 01/20/2015.
The days overdue would be the days between today and the due date. 
 
The due date balance would be 140.00 - 40.00 = 100.00.

That's for only one invoice and one payment transaction but since the reality is a bit more complicated the calculation should reflects the accumulation of both of the days and balance overdue.ie:

Assuming we execute the query on 02/15/2015 with the following data on our customer:

```
Invoice #     Amount     Due Date       
1             140.00     01/15/2015
2             360.00     02/08/2015

Payment #     Amount     Payment Date
1             40.00      01/20/2015
2             100.00     02/18/2015
```

The days overdue would be:
( days elapsed between 02/15/2015 and 01/15/2015 )
 + 
( days elapsed between 02/15/2015 and 02/08/2015 )
  = 31 + 7 = 38 days.
The balance overdue would be 100.00 (the customer made a payment 3 days after the query's date )  + 360.00 = 460.00

I hope it clarifies.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want one row for each instance of a customer having an overdue balance? For example, would you have 2 rows for Customer 2, one showing a balance of 72 and one showing a balance of 43?

Comment: I want only one row. Thanks

Comment: In that case, will it show the sum of the overdue balances? And how do you calculate the number of days overdue if the due dates are different?